# Definable operations

Tags: model-theory

I have to solev next task:
Proove that the operation of multiplication is definable operation in $(\mathbb{N}, + , |)$.

If I define mapping $f: \mathbb{N}^{2} \to \mathbb{N}$, as $f(x,y) = x \cdot y$, I have to show that its graph
$$
G_{f} = \{ (x,y,f(x,y)) : (x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \}
$$
is definable set. So, I need formule which define $G_{f}$.

I tried something but I am not sure that is correct:
Product $x \cdot y$ is natural number, for example $x \cdot y = z$. From here it follows that $x | z$ and $y | z$ and I stopped here. My problem is how to use operations $+$ and $|$ to define formule which I need.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The accepted answer by André Nicolas in the duplicate question answers your question. See also the answer by A. Zarei - Julia Robinson gave a very clever argument showing that multiplication is definable from divisibility and the successor function alone.